# can i use kafka consumer/producer in angular 9. to connect with node server?

Tags: node.js, angular, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to connect Kafka from the client-side using angular-9 with node.js server.

this code is running on node I wanna do the same thing on angular9 "[image: when I install 'kafka-node' on angular-9 it shows an error]

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const bp = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config');

try {
  const Consumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer;
  const client = new kafka.Client(config.kafka_server);
  let consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [{ topic: config.kafka_topic, partition: 0 }],
    {
      autoCommit: true,
      fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
      fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
      encoding: 'utf8',
      fromOffset: false
    }
  );
  consumer.on('message', async function(message) {
    console.log('here');
    console.log(
      'kafka-> ',
      message.value
    );
  })
  consumer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  });
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: If you ship Kafka code to clients, then you need to update your advertised listeners on the brokers... But running Kafka clients in a browser isn't really possible, AFAIK, and best to use websockets

Comment: Yeah I have made a micro service for this to communicate with the backend server and my client-side will communicate with that micro service using socket-io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @OneCricketeer told above If you ship Kafka code to clients, then you need to update your advertised listeners on the brokers... But running Kafka clients in a browser isn't really possible

It's best to use websockets, so I have made a micro service (NodeJs) for this to communicate with the backend server and my client-side will communicate with that micro service(NodeJS) using socket-io

Comment: If i need to use socketio for angular in order to communicate with kafka on the backend, why not get rid of kafka and replace the whole mechanism with socketio...?